# PHP echo next file name relative to the current one open?

Tags: php, glob

PHP `echo` next file name relative to the current one open?

`http://www.example.com/mysceript.php?filename=a.jpg`

```
 $filename = $_GET['filename'];
 echo "<img src=$filename>";
```

that works but I would like list the next file name relative to the open by name (Alphabetically), something like

```
 $nextfilename = relative the open in current directory); 
 echo ($nextfilename);
```

then would print result

```
 b.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [glob](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.glob.php)

like this :

```
$files = glob('*');
sort($files);
$key = array_search($_GET['filename'], $files);
$nextFile = $key != -1 ? $files[$key] : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

increment the filename php increments alphabets too

```
$nextfilename =$filename++; 
 echo ($nextfilename);
```

**update:**

```
$filename = $_GET['filename'];
 echo "<img src=$filename>";
$name=glob(*.*) ;
foreach ($name as $l){
 echo $
}
```

or

```
  $a=scandir(.); 

  echo $a++;
```

[check this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php)

Comment: thanks that just added a number 3 to it want to select hte next file in the directory name, it coudl be anyting

Comment: "it could be anything" means name may vary i.e discrete (A,G,H,L.......)?